# Matching iframe src on index 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe, match, regex-lookarounds

I need to match the url of an iframe src in the index 1. I am using this matchAll function to match multiple occurrences.

```
if (typeof RegExp.prototype.matchAll !== "function") {
    RegExp.prototype.matchAll = function(v) {
        var tmp     = ""+ this, // So this.toString
            src     = tmp.lastIndexOf("/"),
            pattern = tmp.substring(1, src),
            flags   = tmp.substring(src + 1, tmp.length);

        // Never forget "g", that prepends infinite loops for "while"
        if (flags.indexOf("g") == -1) {
            flags += "g";
        }

        var re = new RegExp(pattern, flags);
        var ms = [], m;
        while (m = re.exec(v)) {
            ms.push(m);
        }
        return ms;
    };
}
```

Using this test code:

```
str = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8L-6Hw7CZLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var pattern = /\[embed\](.*?)\[\/embed\]|<iframe.*?src="(.*?)".*?<\/iframe>/;
var matches = pattern.matchAll(str);
console.log(matches);
```

I do get the src, but on index 2, and I need it on index 1, because the pattern actually matches other things that uses the index 1 as the "url" so I rather match all the urls on that index instead of modifying the entire code.

Whats the correct pattern to get the src url on index 1 for any iframe?

Comment: Post the HTML, just in case there's something that didn't occur to you and/or help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: @zer00ne `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/embed/123123[/embed]ffdsads<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8L-6Hw7CZLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make both iframe url and embed url appear on index 1. Try the following code:

```
var pattern = /(?:(?:<iframe.*?src=")|(?:\[embed\]))(.*?)(?:\"|(?=\[\/embed\]))/;
```

Comment: The iframe url match now returns on index 1, but the [embed] match doesn't return the url now, for example with this str `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/embed/123123[/embed]ffdsads<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8L-6Hw7CZLQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: @Mark Which index do you want the [embed] to return to? index 1 or index 2?

Comment: Both iframe url and embed url on index 1 of the multidimensional array. Ex. `Array( [0] => Array( [0] => '[embed]url1[/embed], [1] => url1 ), [1] => Array( [0] => '<iframe ... src="url2" ...></iframe>', [1] => url2 ) );`

Comment: @Mark I updated my answer, try the updated code. Both iframe url and embed url should be now on index 1

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It matches the src of the iframe and between the `[embed][/embed]` in the same group (Group1).

```
var pattern = /(?:(?:\[embed\])|(?:<iframe.*?src="))(.*?)(?:(?:\[\/embed\])|(?:".*?<\/iframe>))/;
```